# Setting a field as primary key in django model

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

I am using django 2.2 with python 3.6.8 on ubuntu 18.04.
I created a model like below :

```
@reversion.register()
class Courses(BaseModel):
    coursecode = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name=_("Kurs Kodu"))
    coursename = models.ForeignKey(CourseNames, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("Kurs"))
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Staff, blank=True,  related_name='teacher', verbose_name=_("Öğretmenler"))
    courseroom = models.ForeignKey(CourseRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("Kurs Yeri"))
    credit = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=_("Kredi"), default=0.0, max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Öğrenci"))
    createdon = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Oluşturulma Tarihi"))
    createdby = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  related_name='creatorstaff', verbose_name=_("Kaydeden Personel"))
    coursenotes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Kurs Notları"))

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("list_course", _("List Courses")),
        )
        ordering = ['coursename']
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.coursename, self.courseroom, self.teacher)
```

When i try to makemigrations i get below error :

> project1app.Courses: (models.E026) The model cannot have more than one field with 'primary_key=True'.

As i set a primarykey field django should not set automatic primarykey and use mine. There is only one field with primarykey. But giving below error.

Comment: Does your `BaseModel` have a field that is a `primary_key=True`?

Comment: Again Willem and again solved question. Thanks my friend. Solved. You can add as an answer.